# Angular is giving me an injection unresolved error, but my controller isn't asking for any injections

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, modal-dialog, inject

I have a modal controller that is buggy, so I've been commenting out code to try to figure out the bug. Currently, my modal HTML partial is an empty div tag and my controller is a single console.log, with no arguments or parameters. The $modal.open call only specifies the controller and the partial.

Now, when I try to open the modal I get an injector error saying that 'orgId' is not resolving. Except I'm not asking for orgId to be injected. I've already cleared the cache (Chrome), ensured that I'm running the correct, latest version of the file, and deleted all (commented or not) instances of the word 'orgId' from the file. Yet it keeps asking for it. As a modal controller, it's not in my router-ui state hierarchy, so it shouldn't be any weird parent-child interaction. Any other ideas of what could be going on?

This is what my code looks like:

Partial.html:
    `<div></div>`

Controller:
    `app.controller( 'ctrl.modal', [
    function () { console.log("Controller is called"); 
} ] )`

Calling Controller:

```
    exercises.controller( 'ctrl.exercisesnew', [ '$scope', '$location', '$stateParams', 'factory.exercises', 'force.services.userservice', '$q',
        '$resource', 'factory.endpoints', '$modal', 'underscore', 'force.factory.classes.usercontext', 'factory.common', 'force.services.unitservice', '$state', 'factory.teep', '$window',
        function ( $scope, $location, $stateParams, ExercisesServices, UserService, $q, $resource, endpoints, $modal, _, UserContext, commonService, UnitService, $state, TeepService, $window ) {
            $scope.c2ram.ctrl.exercisesnew.absorb = function () {
                var assignExerciseDetailsModalInstance = $modal.open( {
                    templateUrl: 'partial.html',
                    controller: 'ctrl.modal'
                } );
            };

        }
    ] );
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: please add some code..How can we detect error without seeing at your code

Comment: Sure, one moment... although it is literally as described:  

Partial.html:  
    `<div></div>`

Controller:  
    `app.controller( 'ctrl.modal', [
        function () { console.log("Controller is called"); 
    } ] )'

$modal.open call:  
    `$modal.open( { templateUrl: 'partial.html', controller: 'ctrl.modal' } );`

Comment: did you inject `$modal` dependancy in your controller from where you are doing `$modal.open`

Comment: Yes, I am doing that injection.

Comment: could you paste that controller too

Comment: Sure! It's really long, one moment

Comment: its wiered all the code looks same..are you using stable version of angular-ui-bootstrap?

Comment: are you using angular strap that will cause conflict with `$modal`

Comment: Hi, so this is super embarassing. Basically when I copied and pasted the modal controller out of the previous place where I had it, I forgot to delete the old (string named) controller. Angular was randomly choosing between the two identically named modal controllers when opening the modal, and giving me no warning that a controller of that name already existed. Whoops!

Comment: Glad to here that it does fixed..

Comment: could you add that as an answer..so that it will help others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is super embarassing. Basically when I copied and pasted the modal controller out of the previous place where I had it, I forgot to delete the old (string named) controller. Angular was randomly choosing between the two identically named modal controllers when opening the modal, and giving me no warning that a controller of that name already existed. Whoops!

To those of you who are reading this answer, check to make sure you don't have any identically named controllers that would be causing a conflict. It's a likely result of any copy and paste error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ui-bootstrap? If you are, you have to inject `$modal` into your controller to use it.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response. I am using ui-bootstrap, and I am injecting $modal into the controller. However, I am injecting nothing into the $modal.open call.